# Android Studio erro ao passar array entre activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que lê o código de barras de um item e compara se ele existe ou não em uma lista com dados do banco. Quando algum desses itens não está presente no banco ele deve gravar os dados em um array e enviá-los para uma outra activity onde irão aparecer em um Spinner. Quando apenas um código precisa ser enviado funciona ok. Porém, quando tento enviar dois ou mais, aparece o seguinte erro ao tentar iniciar a segunda activity:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.weebly.wlhtech.confitem, PID: 24955
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a
>   null object reference

Segue o código das duas activity:

Activity que lê e envia os dados:

```
public void compareData(String patrimonio) {
        for(i=0;i<(lstItens.getAdapter().getCount());i++) {
            Log.d("String ", lstItens.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
            if(patrimonio.contentEquals(lstItens.getItemAtPosition(i).toString())) {
                Log.d("Resultado: igual", lstItens.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                ok = true;
                break;
            } else {
                Log.d("Resultado: diferente", patrimonio);
            }
        }
        if(ok == true) {
            Log.d("Resultado encontrado", String.valueOf(i));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Patrimônio não encontrado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            naoencontrados = new String[100];
            naoencontrados[posicao] = patrimonio;
            posicao +=1;
        }

        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Continuar conferência");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                camera();
            }
        });
        builder.setNeutralButton("Finalizar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                scannerView.stopCameraPreview();
                Intent confSetorResult = new Intent(ListaConf.this, confSetorResult.class);
                confSetorResult.putExtra("nEncontrados", naoencontrados);
                confSetorResult.putExtra("setor", setor);
                startActivity(confSetorResult);

            }
        });
        builder.setMessage("Deseja adicionar mais algum item?");
        android.app.AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Activity que recebe os dados:

```
package com.weebly.wlhtech.confitem;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class confSetorResult extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spnNEncontrados;
    String setor;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conf_setor_result);

        spnNEncontrados = findViewById(R.id.spnNEncontrados);

        //Pegar dados da outra Activity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String[] nEncontrados = intent.getStringArrayExtra("nEncontrados");
        setor = intent.getStringExtra("setor");

        //Popular Spinner
        if(nEncontrados == null) {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 0);
            spnNEncontrados.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nEncontrados);

            spnNEncontrados.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

    public void alterar(View v) {
        Intent altera = new Intent(this, AlteraSetor.class);
        altera.putExtra("Setor", setor);
        altera.putExtra("Patrimonio", spnNEncontrados.getSelectedItem().toString());
        altera.putExtra("Nome", 0);
        startActivity(altera);
    }
}
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar no que está errado?

Comment: Se possível informe em qual trecho do código, ocorre o erro citado.

Comment: Editei na pergunta. O erro acontece ao iniciar a activity, ele não chega a abrir a segunda tela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
 ArrayList<String> nEncontrados = new ArrayList<>();
```

Preenchar os dados da nEncontrados exemplo:

```
lista.add("1");
lista.add("2");
```

etc...

Depois passe ele pela intent assim:

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("nEncontrados", nEncontrados);
```

E capture na outra Activity assim:

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 List<String> lista = bundle.getStringArrayList("nEncontrados");
```

É interessante destacar que foi usando um List e não um vetor, como você esta usando.

Comment: Você quer que o primeiro a ser adicionado seja o primeiro da lista ? Se for isso, funciona sim, pode utilizar assim: lista.get(posição); Só cuidado para não ter "Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception"

Comment: muito obrigada, me ajudou bastante também :D